# How to customize Bootstrap 5 Color theme frontend only

Tags: css, sass, frontend, bootstrap-5

I'm using Flask as a Web server and thus have to use static .js and .css files.
I want to adjust the color theme of Bootstrap.
This is unfortunately not easily possible via CSS variables, as button colors etc are compiled from sass.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what i found to be the most elegant solution: Compile bootstrap.css

The steps are:

1.) Install [this](https://sass-lang.com/install/) Sass compiler (i used an npm installation and used `npm install -g sass`

2.) download the latest bootstrap source code. for example: [Bootstrap 5.2](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/download/) and click "Download source"

3.) Create a folder and put the unzipped files into a folder called bootstrap and follow this file structure:

```
your-project/
├── scss
│   └── custom.scss
└── bootstrap/
    ├── js
    └── scss
```

[source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/)

4.) create a custom style file like this:

```
// Custom.scss
// Option A: Include all of Bootstrap

// Include any default variable overrides here (though functions won't be available)

// Default variable overrides
$primary: #216487;
$secondary: #4f616e;

$danger: #ba1a1a;

$body-bg: #f6fafe;


@import "../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// Then add additional custom code here
```

5.) Compile the bootrap.css with the command `sass .\custom.scss .\bootstrap.css`

the resulting bootstrap.css file can be used as a replacement for the default pre-compiled bootstrap.css file and thus gives a custom color pallet.

run the command